# JavaScript: "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" last line of file

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I am getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 120)

I have run the JavaScript parts through a validator and it doesn't complain about any missing brackets.

I have tried to find similar errors where the missing error line is the last line of the file, without luck.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.changed); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.json("{% url 'deliver_json' % }", function(error, data) {

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });

  var metrics = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, changed: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.versions.date; }));

  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.versions.changed; }));


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Changed");

  var metric = svg.selectAll(".name")
      .data(metrics)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "name");

  metrics.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  metrics.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.changed) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

}

</script>
```

The JSON that is fetched is of the following format:

```
[{"date": 20000102, "version": "version_name", "changed": 2}, ..., ...]
```

Any idea what could be wrong? It seems so weird that it goes through syntax checkers fine and then it complains about the last line (120)...

Comment: You're missing a `);` at the end of your script to close the call to `d3.json`

Comment: there is an open parens after `d3.json` and no closer anywhere for it.

Comment: Maybe you should use better syntax checker; try http://jslint.com

Comment: My answer was first by the way. Why did you accepted the last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the d3.json(

At the end of your code:

```
    }

</script>
```

should be:

```
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Whats problem? Add `);` at the end of your `<script>` and error disappears

```
  ...
.text(function(d) { return d.name; });

});
 ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not close your `d3.json` call anywhere...You should add a closing parens at the end of the call and that should fix that particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing closing bracket for `d3.json(`. So add a closing bracket ')' after '}' in the end.